# how to visualize multiple json files with mapboxgl-jupyter?

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, mapbox-gl

let's say I have two json files:

```
file_A = 'file_A.json'
file_B = 'file_B.json'
```

I can use mapboxgl-jupyter for one file as following:

```
from mapboxgl.utils import *
from mapboxgl.viz import *

viz = ChoroplethViz(file_A, 
                    access_token=MAPBOX_TOKEN,
                    color_property='contenance',
                    color_stops=create_color_stops([0, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000], colors='YlOrRd'),
                    color_function_type='contenance',
                    line_stroke='-',
                    line_color= None,#'rgb(255,255,255)',
                    line_width=1,
                    opacity=0.9,
                    center=(3, 42.5),
                    zoom=7,
                    below_layer='waterway-label')
viz.show()
```

But how to show both files on the same map?

I have tried to merge all json files into one with `jsonmerge` but it often needs some extra care on how dicts are merged as it can make some mistakes.